# I have an app created in expo that does not show the map on huawei devices, how can I fix this?

Tags: react-native, google-maps, expo, harmonyos, huawei-map-kit

With the addition of HarmonyOS, the map that is from google is not available for Huawei devices.
If I add the map that Huawei created for its devices, it will not be compatible with Android.
Any ideas?

Comment: You could use a package like like react-native-device-info to detect a Huawei device and show the appropriate map.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [plug-in](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/client-dev-0000001138591439?ha_source=hms1) to determine whether your phone is a Huawei devices. The method returns a status code which indicates the HMS Core status on device.

```
HMSAvailability.isHuaweiMobileServicesAvailable()
    .then((res) => { console.log(JSON.stringify(res)) })
    .catch((err) => { console.log(JSON.stringify(err)) });
```